# BATCH - Use FOR loop on directory files, ordered on Creation date/time

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm wanting to order files in a directory based on date of creation (or at least, last modified).

I have this code:

```
FOR /R "directory" %%F IN (*.filetype) DO echo "command" "%%F" > "another\directory\%%~nF.tsv"
```

...which runs a for loop on files in no particular order (alphabetically?).

What I want to be able to do is:

```
FOR /R "direcotry\*.filetype" %%F IN ('dir /o-d /b "directory"') DO echo "command" "%%F" > "another\directory\%%~nF.tsv"
```

The lower code doesn't work, but you may see what I mean.
I'm proficient in `BASH` but not in `BATCH`

The key is `dir /o-d /b "drive:\directory\*.filetype"`, which orders by creation date (reverse order), and then spits out only the file name -- but I don't know how to work this into a for loop for taking file names, and then running a command on them.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('dir /o-d /tc /b /s "directory\*.filetype"') DO echo "command" "%%F" >> "another\directory\%%~nF.tsv"
```

`for/f` to process a "file" of text.

`"delims="` to turn tokenising off so the entire line of "output" from the `dir` is assigned.

`/tc` to use creation date (`o/[-]d` omitted = alphabetical order from an NTFS drive, storge-order on FAT)

`/s` to add subdiectories

`>>` to append to output file.

OR

```
...DO "command" "%%F"
```

to execute the command directly without creating the file.

Comment: Right answer however there is a limitation in `dir /S /O-D` where switches `/S` and `/O` are used concurrently: sorting is applied _inside_ each (sub)directory!

Answer (score 0):

Due to the limitation mentioned in the comment to the other answer, here is a potential workaround leveraging PowerShell:

```bat
@For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'Powershell "(GCI "directory" -R *.filetype|Sort CreationTime -Des)|%%{$_.Fullname}"'
) Do @"command" "%%A">"another\directory\%%~nA.tsv"
```

*Obviously adjusting `directory`, `filetype`, `"command"` and `another\directory` as required*